# Extracting contiguous rows in an array

Tags: python, dataframe, julia

The following code in python

```
df['tag'] = df['Value'] < 1.0 
df['mask'] = np.where(df['tag'],1,0)
first = df.index[df['tag'] & ~ df['tag'].shift(1).fillna(False)]
last = df.index[df['tag'] & ~ df['tag'].shift(-1).fillna(False)]
pr = [(i, j) for i, j in zip(first, last) if j > i + 1]
```

returns an array, pr, that contains tuples of contiguous rows lesser than the Value of 1. I have tried to translate this Julia to a partial extent as follows:

```
df[:tag]=df[:Value] .< 1.0
df[:mask]=zeros(length(df[:tag]))

df[:mask][df[:tag].==true] .= 1
df[:mask][df[:tag].==false] .= 0
```

How can I replicate the values for first, last, pr in Julia?

Comment: I implemented the solution without `j > i + 1` condition as I am not clear why it is needed.

Comment: Without this condition, some blocks would be of zero length. I wanted blocks of size greater than zero.

Comment: But `j > i + 1` means that `j` must be at least `i+2` which implies block length of at least 3. assume that you have an input vector `[0.5, 0.5]`. With this condition `pr` is `[]`. Is this what you wanted? I thought you wanted to get `[(0,1)]` (in Python), or equivalently `[(1,2)]` in Julia in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you two possible approaches to this problem. The first is faster, but requires a bit more code. The second is slower, but shorter.

```
function getblocks1(vs)
    blocks = Tuple{Int, Int}[]
    inblock, start = false, 0, 0
    for (i, v) in enumerate(vs)
        if inblock
            if v >= 1.0
                push!(blocks, (start, i-1))
                inblock = false
            end
        else
            if v < 1.0
                start = i
                inblock = true
            end
        end
    end
    inblock && push!(blocks, (start, length(vs)))
    blocks
end

function getblocks2(vs)
    t = [false; vs .< 1.0; false]
    dt = diff(t)
    f = findall(==(1), dt)
    l = findall(==(-1), dt) .- 1
    collect(zip(f, l))
end
```

The crucial thing to know, that in Julia `getblocks1` will be fast because loops in Julia are fast and the function tries to minimize the number of allocations and does everything in one pass. The second implementation is more Python-like, but allocates more and does several passes through the whole vector.